# Why the following code doesn't compile in MSVC and does in g++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, c++20, initializer-list

I am trying to use the constructor initializer list with the colon in main, but it doesn't compile in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 (Error: identifier "name" is undefined & expected a '}')
, but it compiles and prints the output without any problem in g++ (version 10.2.0) in Linux.

I have also tried different versions of MSVC, like C++14, C++17 with no result.
I know all the possible initializations of C++11 but I must use the one with the colon( : ).

Is there a way to do it in MSVC?

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Spell {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string action;

public:
    Spell(std::string name, std::string action) : name(name), action(action) {}

    void print() {
        std::cout << name;
    }
};

int main() {

    Spell* spell = new Spell{ name : "test", action : "lol" }; //HERE
    spell->print();
}
```

Comment: compile the code in gcc with -`pedantic` and you'll see stuff like * warning: ISO C++ does not allow GNU designated initializers*. Standard compliant code is a must if you want portability.

Answer (score 5):

That syntax is a non-standard GNU extension, and thus is not (and likely never will be) supported by any version of Microsoft Visual C++.

Designated initializers were standardized in C++20, but the syntax is different and they are only available for aggregate initialization.  The equivalent standard designated initializer syntax would be `Spell{.name = "test", .action = "lol"}`.  That won't work in this case either though, since `Spell` is not an aggregate because it has private data members and a user-defined constructor.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your answer. I also found this https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm
In my case though, it just calls the constructor and it has nothing to do with the fields. The following code compiles successfully: `class Spell {
public:
 Spell(std::string name, std::string action) {}

};

int main() {
 Spell * spell = new Spell{ name : "test", action : "lol" };
}`